# "Whole function VS just the function statements" inside the brace

Tags: scala

What is the diference between func1 and func2 body. Both compiles but I couldn't figure out how scala can recognize multiple statements in func2 as brace is putted before `a =>` but the statements are after that.

```
val func1: Int => Int = a => {
  val b = a * 2
  b + 2
}

val func2: Int => Int = { a =>
  val b = a * 2
  b + 2
}
```

Even this one compiles

```
val func3: Int => Int = { a => val b = a * 2; b + 2 }
```

But this one doesn't

```
val func4: Int => Int = a => val b = a * 2; b + 2
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because when you don't use `{}` you can only have one expression and `val b = a * 2; b + 2` are two expressions. The parser considers it something like:

```
val func4: Int => Int = a => val b = a * 2; 

b + 2
```

Which doesn't compile because there isn't a `b` in scope and the type of the expression `val b = a * 2;` is Unit, which doesn't satisfies `func4`s type.

Other than that, func 1 through 3 are equivalent.

Comment: I'm curious about the difference between func1 and func2; `a => { ... }` vs `{ a => ... }`.

Comment: None. As soon as you provide a delimiter you are free to use as many expressions as you want and it will be delimited to the same scope.